# Error on installing boto3 - python-dateutil 1.5

Tags: python, pip, macos-sierra, boto3, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to install boto3 on my Mac running High Sierra for AWS Cli and I keep getting the following error:

```
Collecting boto3
  Using cached boto3-1.5.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.30 (from boto3)
  Using cached botocore-1.8.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 (from boto3)
  Using cached s3transfer-0.1.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.30->boto3)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.30->boto3)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" (from s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10->boto3)
  Using cached futures-3.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.30->boto3)
Installing collected packages: python-dateutil, botocore, futures, s3transfer, boto3
  Found existing installation: python-dateutil 1.5
    Uninstalling python-dateutil-1.5:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil', '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7b/yjnqplp56yq9g01b4z6zfpww0000gn/T/pip-VFHRFW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil'")]
```

I have tried running pip uninstall python-dateutil to uninstall it to reinstall in case something has gone wrong with it but that produces the same error. Tired running the commands with sudo but still get the same error.

Is there anyway of fixing this? Or another way of installing boto3?

I'm using Pip version 9.0.1 and Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it now.

I used:

```
sudo pip install -ignore-installed python-util
```

Which meant I could then install boto3 as it was no longer looking at the old version 1.5 and trying to uninstall it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this

```
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed python-dateutil
```

Post that the following

```
sudo pip install boto3
```

Thanks